# Making road like in YT tutorial trouble

Tags: modifiers

When I use curve modifier with array modifier to make a road this happens:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATj93.jpg

tutorial I work with:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPmzhqfw-7I

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6396" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6396/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your file you didn't create any *Curve* modifier, so nothing happens. Put the *Curve* modifier below the *Array* modifier. You'll see that your object is completely swollen. That's because you have somehow played with the vertices radius as you can see in the 3D view *T* panel if you select the curve, switch to *Edit* mode and select all. Bring this value back to 1.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I'd never realise i messed up something there

Answer (score 1):

### verify the following

- first place the array modifier
- then place the curve modifier
- select the object in the object list of the curve modifier
- return to array modifier and increase or decrease the number of segments you need

***NOTE:*** *you must apply scale and rotation with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to the curve and also to the object, take into account that the result can vary according to the size of the object and the acute angle of the curves*

[image]

**You can follow the configuration that I have in my image so that it fits your model**

[image]

### error examples

[image]
[image]

### FIX THE PROBLEM

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Download The blend File click in the PUMPKIN

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately something still doesn't work for me and this happens:
https://imgur.com/a/LlhMCKl

It doesn't fit my curve at all

Comment: ok, let me check the image

Comment: check again the answer and download the example blend file, try to practice with this ok

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on @moonboots' answer, because I've been confused by it myself, in the past.

Every vertex on a curve has a radius; in the illustration below, the leftmost vertex has a radius of 3, the rightmost 0.5.

[image]

- (as shown above..) If Curve Normals are displayed, they show the radii.
- **If** 'Radius' is checked in the curve's Shape panel, the radii will influence the radial scale of anything following, or deformed by, the curve. You can switch the influence off.
- In Edit mode, if, as above, you select 1 vertex, the 'Radius' field of the Properties Region > Transform panel will  show its radius, and you can adjust its value there.

[image]

- ... if you select more than one vertex, the field becomes 'Mean Radius', and shows the average radius in the selection.

[image]

- If you adjust the Mean Radius (to 1, in the example above), all the radii in the selection are uniformly scaled, so their *average* becomes the requested value.

[image]

- If you want to set an *absolute* value for the radius on a selection of vertices, you can do it in the Tool Region > 'Set Curve Radius'.